# Random forest invalid data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification, random-forest

I'm trying to classify forest habitats at a 10-meter resolution. I have imported my points from a shapefile that contains habitat categories for each sampled point in the "target" column. I want to train a random forest classification to map all the forests obtained by creating a forest mask for the entire Lazio region. The input data consists of soil-climatic raster data.

I have written this script that works up to line 84

```
(models.getInfo().forEach(function(modelInfo) {
  var accuracy = modelInfo.accuracy;
  if (accuracy > maxAccuracy) {
    maxAccuracy = accuracy;
    bestModel = modelInfo.model;)
```

where I encounter this error:

> ("Line 85: No valid training data were found").

I can't figure out where the error is, as my variable "trainingData" appears to be composed of the bands of the input data.

How can I resolve this?

```
// Training points
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(Forest_point);

/// Add the input variables (30 rasters manually inserted)
var inputVariables = [
  Bulk_density.rename('Bulk_soil'),
  Clay.rename('Clay_10m'),
  Temperature.rename('Temp'),
  Bulk3060_density.rename('Bulk3060_1'),
  Precipitation.rename('Prec'),
  DEM.rename('Dem'),
  Soil_Carbon.rename('Soil_Org_C'),
  Sand3060.rename('Sand3060_1'),
  RH_atm.rename('RH'),
  Silt.rename('Silt_10m'),
  Nitrogen.rename('nitrog_soi'),
  VWC.rename('VWC_soil'),
  Aspect.rename('Aspect'),
  Easterness.rename('Easterness'),
  Northerness.rename('Northernes'),
  Slope.rename('Slope'),
  Dist_costa.rename('Dist_coast'),
  Dist_fiumi.rename('Dist_river'),
  Radiation.rename('Radiation'),
  Depth_bedrock.rename('Depth_bedr')
];


// Combine the rasters into a single image
var trainingData = ee.Image.cat(inputVariables);
print (trainingData, 'training data')
// Sample the points and add them as bands to the image
trainingData = trainingData.addBands(points.reduceToImage(['TEST'], ee.Reducer.mean()));
print (trainingData, 'training data1')
// Split the data into training and validation sets (70% training, 30% validation)
var split = ee.FeatureCollection(Forest_point);
var withRandom = split.randomColumn('split');
var training = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('split', 0.7));
var validation = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('split', 0.7));

// Define the mask
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection(Maschera);

// Apply the mask to the training image
trainingData = trainingData.clipToCollection(mask);

// Define the configuration for the Random Forest
var rfConfig = {
  numberOfTrees: 500,
  variablesPerSplit: 15,
  minLeafPopulation: 2
};

// Create a list of trained models with cross-validation
var models = ee.List.repeat(0, 20).map(function(i) {
  var trainFold = training.filter(ee.Filter.eq('fold', i));
  var valFold = validation.filter(ee.Filter.eq('fold', i));
// Get the band names from each image and concatenate into a single array
  var inputBands = ee.List(inputVariables.map(function(image) {
    return ee.Image(image).bandNames();
  })).flatten().distinct();

  var rf = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(rfConfig).train({
    features: trainFold,
    classProperty: 'target',
    inputProperties: inputBands
  });
  
  var validationAccuracy = valFold
    .classify(rf)
    .errorMatrix('TEST', 'classification')
    .accuracy();
  
  return {
    model: rf,
    accuracy: validationAccuracy
  };
});

// Select the model with the highest accuracy
var bestModel = null;
var maxAccuracy = -1;

models.getInfo().forEach(function(modelInfo) {    
  var accuracy = modelInfo.accuracy;
  if (accuracy > maxAccuracy) {
    maxAccuracy = accuracy;
    bestModel = modelInfo.model;
  }
});

// Ensure that a better model has been selected
if (bestModel !== null) {
// Train the Random Forest on the complete dataset
  var finalModel = ee.Classifier(bestModel);

// Classify the target image using the final model within the mask
var classified = trainingData.classify(finalModel, 'classification');

// Calculate the classification uncertainty
  var uncertainty = classified.expression(
    '1 - prob',
    {
      'prob': classified.select('classification').clip(mask.geometry()).reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev())
    }
  );

// Display the classified image and the uncertainty map
  Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['00FF00', 'FF0000']}, 'Classified Image');
  Map.addLayer(uncertainty, {min: 0, max: 0.5, palette: ['gray', 'blue']}, 'Uncertainty Map');

// Calculate the confusion matrix on the validation subset
  var confusionMatrix = validation
    .classify(finalModel)
    .errorMatrix('TEST', 'classification');

// Display the confusion matrix
  print('Confusion Matrix:', confusionMatrix);

// Calculate the accuracy on the validation subset
  var accuracy = confusionMatrix.accuracy();
  print('Accuracy:', accuracy);
} else {
  print('Nessun miglior modello selezionato.');
}
```